# How to calculate directional light in GLSL shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

Various examples of directional lights are all too varied to try and get a coherent picture of what's supposed to be happening; Some examples use matrices with unexplained contents and others, just use the vertex normal and light direction.

I've been attempting to write a shader based on what made the most sense to me but currently it leaves a scene fully lit or fully unlit; Dependent on the light direction.

In my fragment shader:

```
float diffuseFactor = dot(vertexNormal, -lightDirection)
vec4 diffuseColor = lightColor * diffuseFactor;
fragColor = color * diffuseColor;
```

So am I way off? Do I need to pass in more information (e.g: modelViewMatrix?) to achieved the desired result?

Comment: You need to choose a space to do the calcualtions in. Typically, lighting is done in world space or eye space. What you seem to do here is object space - this is possible, too. But this means that `lightDirection` is used as if it is in object space, too. But it requires you to update `lightDirection` whenever your object is rotated, and it means that the `lightDirection` will vary per object (assuming some independent rotations per object).

Comment: I see, if I understand correctly I'm just using the vertex normal, as is and should be applying the model and world transforms to it. However, shouldn't I still be seeing different colours/shades for different normals?

Comment: Well you should, assuming both `vertexNormal` and `lightDirection` are actually unit lenght vectors.

Comment: They should be, so I guess I have more problems that just my shader. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Your question is not actually what you're asking. Your question is "what book is better than the ones I already found", so I voted to close this. Here is your answer: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming

Comment: The question I asked, while perhaps not implicitly stated, was 'what am I doing wrong?' and derhass has answered it. Your link appears to be a handy reference but would not have helped as I didn't know what the problem was. Also; It appears to be quite poor learning material for a novice. So far, I have got along best with Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming by Jason McKesson. [link](http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html)